Python inheritance with @dataclasses.dataclass and annotations
I am very confused by the following code:
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass()
class Base():
  x: int = 100

@dataclasses.dataclass()
class Derived(Base):
  x: int = 200

@dataclasses.dataclass()
class DerivedRaw(Base):
  x = 300


base = Base()
derived = Derived()
derived_raw = DerivedRaw()

print(base.x)
print(derived.x)
print(derived_raw.x)

What it prints is:
100
200
100

I don't understand why the last number isn't 300. Why do the annotations matter?
This seems to be an interaction with @dataclasses.dataclass(), as the code:
class Base():
  x: int = 100

class DerivedRaw(Base):
  x = 300

derived_raw = DerivedRaw()

print(derived_raw.x)

Does print 300.

From the dataclass documentation:

The @dataclass decorator examines the class to find fields. A field is defined as a class variable that has a type annotation.
...

So to have proper dataclass field must have type annotation.
